# How to return to old chmod owner permissions after changing all to root

Tags: permissions, chmod

I did the command

> chmod -R www-data:www-data /

But after that, nothing worked. So i found on the internet that you can returen back to your default permissions with:

> perl -0ne '$_ =~ m{^(\d*\d\d\d) (.*)\0$} ; print "chmod $1 $2\n" ;
>   chmod oct($1), $2 ;' working-permissions.txt

But is there some that could work with the groupowners?

Comment: Please add a few lines from "working-permissions.txt"  The contents of that file are used to recreate those permissions. The $1 and $2 will be a column in that file where $1 is the permission and $2 the file name. Rename "chmod" to "chgrp" but that will not be correct for all files: the $1 is probably going to be 1 column to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean you used the **chown** command. The command you provide is invalid.

If that is indeed the case you will find that the question is pretty much similar to this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48845/how-to-revert-chown-command.

It turns out there is indeed not an easy fix for this. You will probably have to spend time manually restoring ownership of many files and folders, accessing them though a recovery drive. Something like this: http://www.system-rescue-cd.org.